# How does template type deduction work when multiple parameters make use of the same template type? (C++20)

Tags: c++, templates

For example, the following code block fails to compile:

```
template <typename T>
void WithOptional(T o1, std::optional<T> o2) {}

int main()
{
    WithOptional(1, 1);
}
```

Here is a snippet of the compiler error:

> could not match 'std::optional' against 'int'

On the other hand, this code does compile:

```
template <typename T>
void WithVector(T o1, std::vector<T> o2) {}

int main()
{
    WithVector(1, {1});
}
```

I'm a bit confused on the discrepancy here. In both cases, the second argument has a type different from the parameter: for the first block, I pass in an int instead of an std::optional and in the second case, a std::initializer_list instead of a std::vector. Why does the second code snippet compile?

Comment: `{..}` has no type, and can only be deduced to few type.

Comment: `1` is an int and not an `std::optional` (even if convertible).

Comment: `template <typename T> void WithOptional(T, std::type_identity_t<std::optional<T>>)` might be an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{1}` is not a `std::initializer_list`. It's not of any type at all: `{1}` is not an expression. `{1}` is, effectively, *a special part of the function call syntax*, and is handled specially by deduction. Specifically, an braced-init-list used as an argument [does not contribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) to template argument deduction unless the function parameter is already declared to be a `std::initializer_list`, reference thereof, or an array.

So, in the call `WithVector(1, {1})`, `WithVector`'s `T` can only be deduced from the expression `1`, as the second parameter is declared as neither a `std::initializer_list` nor an array. `T` is successfully deduced to `int`, and then that reveals that `{1}` should be used to initialize a `std::vector<int>`.

(I don't remember the reference for the quote, but the committee's intent with braced-init-lists was to have them *look like* expressions but *not be* expressions and instead be special convenience syntax for use under certain constructs, such as function calls and `return` statements. IMO that was certainly a choice.)